# Trouble reading in values from file

Tags: c

My data looks like this:

```
  4.2    6.0

  3.1    4.0

 10.5   10.0

 23.0    8.0

 9.7     4.0

 15.9    5.0
```

I am trying to read in two values at a time, assign them to my variable, and print out the results. I can't figure out **why the values are not getting read in**. My template prints out to my output txt file but none of my values below it print out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define INPUT_FILE "lab3.dat"
#define ANSWER_FILE "lab3.txt"

int main(void)
{
int nsides;
double radius;
double perimeter;
double area;

FILE* my_data;
FILE* out_file;

my_data = fopen(INPUT_FILE, "r");
if(my_data == NULL)
{
    printf("Error on opening the data file\n");
    exit(0);
}

out_file = fopen(ANSWER_FILE,"w");
if(out_file == NULL)
{   
    printf("Error on opening the output file\n");
    exit(0);
}

perimeter = 2*nsides*radius*sin(M_PI/nsides);
area = 0.5*nsides*(radius*radius)*sin((2*M_PI)/nsides);

fprintf(out_file, "\nNima Sarrafzadeh. Lab 3.\n\n");
fprintf(out_file, "         Number Perimeter Area Of \n");
fprintf(out_file, " Radius Of Sides Of Polygon Polygon \n");
fprintf(out_file, "-------- -------- ------------ ----------- \n");
while((fscanf(my_data, "%d%d", &radius, &nsides))==2){
    fprintf(out_file, "%d %d %d %d",radius, nsides, perimeter, area, "\n");
}

fclose(my_data);
fclose(out_file);
}
```

Comment: You need to calculate `area` and `perimeter` for each pair of numbers you read - in the `while()` loop, after the call to `fscanf()` and before the call to `fprintf()`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin There's an `fscanf()` buried in the `while()`-loop conditional clause.

Comment: Yes, I missed it burried under the header `:)` (after the computation had been made without it)

Comment: If you aren't printing out any values then you know exactly where your problem is: `(fscanf(my_data, "%d%d", &radius, &nsides))==2` is false on the first time to that `while` loop.  Why is that? And you'll answer your own question (or ask a better one about how to use `fscanf`).

Answer (score 2):

Where your immediate issue arises, is your attempt to mix your `integer` and `double` reads from the file. Since the file contains values with a *decimal point*, you will need to read both as `double` (or `float`) and then take the real part for your integer `nsides`.

Your compiler should also be screaming warnings at you for your use of both `fscanf` and `fprintf` (specifically given the invalid pointer types and too many arguments for format). If you do not see a number of warning, make sure you always compile with ***warnings enabled*** (e.g. with `-Wall -Wextra`, and for just about all possible warnings, add `-pedantic`) Do not accept code that compiles with any warnings.

If you rethink your format strings a bit, and include the `'\n'` in the format string where it belongs, you can do something like the following: (note it takes the filenames for input/output as the first and second arguments, respectively (defaulting to read/write to `stdin/stdout` if no arguments are given))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int nsides = 0;
    double radius, perimeter, area, ntmp;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin,
         *ofp = argc > 2 ? fopen (argv[1], "w+") : stdout;

    if (!fp || !ofp) {  /* validate files open for reading/writing */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* write heading to output file */
    fprintf (ofp, "\nNima Sarrafzadeh. Lab 3.\n\n"
                  "          Number  Perimeter     Area Of \n"
                  " Radius  Of Sides Of Polygon    Polygon \n"
                  "-------- -------- ------------ ----------- \n");

    /* validate 2 values read for each iteration */
    while (fscanf (fp, " %lf %lf", &radius, &ntmp) == 2) {
        nsides = (int)ntmp;
        perimeter = 2*nsides*radius*sin(M_PI/nsides);
        area = 0.5*nsides*(radius*radius)*sin((2*M_PI)/nsides);
        fprintf (ofp, "%7.2lf %7d %10.2lf %10.2lf\n",
                radius, nsides, perimeter, area);
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin  */
    if (ofp != stdout) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdout */

    return 0;
}
```

Pay particular attention to the ***validate*** comment regarding `fscanf`.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/perim <dat/pairs.txt

Nima Sarrafzadeh. Lab 3.

          Number  Perimeter     Area Of
 Radius  Of Sides Of Polygon    Polygon
-------- -------- ------------ -----------
   4.20       6      25.20      45.83
   3.10       4      17.54      19.22
  10.50      10      64.89     324.02
  23.00       8     140.83    1496.24
   9.70       4      54.87     188.18
  15.90       5      93.46     601.09
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. The reason why I wasn't seeing errors was because I was using PuTTy I think. I don't really get why you used int argc, char **argv though, I haven't seen that before.

Comment: `char *argv[]` is equivalent to `char **argv` when used in the parameter list of a function (`i.e. main()`) because when an array is passed as a parameter, the array is converted to a *pointer*) Thus `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` are equivalent.